# Topmed File Requirements

Tags: vcf, imputation

I am trying to run my VCF's through Topmed Imputation (https://imputation.biodatacatalyst.nhlbi.nih.gov/#!pages/home)

I am trying to make sure that I have the correct requirements for my file to be able to run through the software. These requirements are:

Create a separate vcf.gz file for each chromosome.

Variations must be sorted by genomic position.

GRCh37 or GRCh38 coordinates are required.

I have managed to split my VCF into each chromosome but I am unsure how to check which coordinates are being used and if my file is sorted by genomic position. Are there unix commands I can use to check, or do I just look in the file, Ive looked and not noticed anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are tools that allows you to sort your VCF file by genomic position like [bcftools sort](http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#sort) or [vcf-sort](https://vcftools.github.io/perl_module.html#vcf-sort). But if you don't want to install these software, you could always do with bash tools for one vcf:

```bash
# get the header of your VCF and write to file 'sorted.vcf'
# if your file has the extension .gz, use zgrep instead
grep "^#" your.vcf > sorted.vcf

# get the rest of the lines not starting with '#', sort them first by chromosome, then position and add them to file 'sorted.vcf'
grep -v "^#" your.vcf | sort -V -k1,1 -k2,2n >> sorted.vcf
```

But since you have one file for each chromosome and assuming that your files look like `sample_chrZ.vcf.gz`, where `Z` is the chromosome number, you will have to do a loop:

```bash
mkdir sorted_vcf
for chr in *.vcf.gz; do
   filename="${chr%.*}"
   zgrep "^#" "$chr" > sorted_vcf/"$filename"
   zgrep -v "^#" "$chr" | sort -V -k1,1 -k2,2n  >> sorted_vcf/"$filename"
   bgzip sorted_vcf/"$filename"
done
```

And if you want to know whether your VCF has been aligned against GRCh38 or GRCh37, check the header in the VCF file with a line starting with `##reference=`. A command-line like `grep "##reference=" your.vcf` should give you the result. However, if you don't have the reference mentioned in your VCF file, this is going to be harder to guess. This [post](https://www.biostars.org/p/146171/) should help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi, are you familiar with TopMed?

Comment: Hello, no I am not, sorry. I answered your questions according to your need.